# How to optimize wordpress website and Db properly?

Tags: optimization, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using wp-minify and css and scripts file aggregation plugin for website optimization.
Can anybody answer the following

- Which plugin is considered good for Database optimization?
- How to add expiry headers to javascripts,images and stylesheet?
- Which plugin is good for enabling cache for website's better performance?

Comment: Ask Google, so many articles about WP optimization.

Comment: Consider having a dedicated MySQL server - you'll see a huge performance gain (If you can afford it in budget)

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins that helps to create a cache and instead of fetching content from the database the content is loaded from the cache i.e. html version.

Moreover, you need to follow the few SEO guidelines that I have mentioned below to optimize your wordpress website for search engine like Google.

http://wordpress-tuts.blogspot.com/2017/05/best-ways-to-optimize-and-boost-seo-of.html

Comment: W3 Total Cache, WP Super Cache  are the popular ones.

Answer (score 0):

For expiry headers you can modify the .htaccess file in your website root folder. You can set the expiry time for all files in said root.

Here is a simple guide:
http://softstribe.com/wordpress/how-to-add-expires-headers-in-wordpress/

Comment: please summarize the guide here